# `at` only runs when I add a new job

Tags: linux, bash, cron, archlinux, at-utility

As the title says, I'm having a weird behaviour with `at`:
It put my jobs on queue, and run then correctly, but only after another job is scheduled:

[image]

This is the situation, when I add ad new job then job 17 gets executed.

`atd` service is running fine. My system is: `Linux 5.10.98-1-MANJARO`.

PS: I already tried telling it to not email me `-M`, or using absolute/relative paths, etc... jobs are executed, only when atd is "triggered" or gets awaked by scheduling a new job or restarting the systemd service.

PPS: don't know if this could help, its the log for `atd.service` when I check the status

```sh
feb 22 09:12:01 sant-nuc systemd[1]: Starting Deferred execution scheduler...
feb 22 09:12:01 sant-nuc systemd[1]: Started Deferred execution scheduler.
feb 22 14:16:44 sant-nuc atd[157517]: pam_unix(atd:session): session opened for user santiago(uid=1000) by (uid=2)
feb 22 14:16:44 sant-nuc atd[157517]: pam_env(atd:setcred): deprecated reading of user environment enabled
feb 22 14:16:44 sant-nuc atd[157517]: pam_env(atd:setcred): deprecated reading of user environment enabled
feb 22 14:16:44 sant-nuc atd[157517]: pam_unix(atd:session): session closed for user santiago
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in `at 3.2.4`:
https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=1004972

Apparently this will be fixed in version 3.2.5. It's not available yet through the archlinux repo so I have downgraded to 3.2.2, which does not have this issue.

Comment: oh thanks! This was driving me nuts :D never thought it could be a bug